# Useful operators not yet implemented

Tags: c#, operators

Is there room in C# for a `but` operator in C#?

i.e.:

```
if (checkBox.Checked but comboBox.SelectedItem == null) { ... }
```

as opposed to

```
if (checkBox.Checked == false || (checkBox.Checked && comboBox.SelectedItem != null)) { ... }
```

What other currently non-existent operators could be useful to save typing out a less readable statement?

**UPDATE**
KennyTM has posted an [*excellent* alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071185/useful-operators-not-yet-implemented/4071203#4071203) to the `but` operator I suggested, but it's kind've missing the point.  I know the existing operators can be combined to create *any* expression possible, I'm just wondering how better my code might express my intent.

I.e. *"if the checkbox is not checked or nothing is selected"* doesn't scan *quite* as well as *"if the checkbox is checked but nothing is selected"*.

**UPDATE 2:**
Just an update for those who say that "and" is the same as "but". While I agree that logically that is correct (and I'm not re-opening this issue) I wanted to a share a quote with you that suggests the choice between "and" and "but" can sometimes make a big difference:

> [Had a curry for lunch in our customers canteen. It looked a bit like cat sick **but** it was quite tasty.](http://twitter.com/#!/Plip/status/40030894798544896)
>   *Phil Winstanley - 22nd Feb 2011*

Many thanks. :)

Comment: How do I make this community wiki?

Comment: flag the post to moderators. They will do it for you

Comment: we seriously need a butt operator :)

Comment: Maybe we could use an operator for almost. Or maybe. 65 ~ 65.5

Comment: Why would you define a logic operator that doesn't match the English reading of the sentence?  example: *If it is raining but the window is still open* has the same meaning as this C#: `if (raining && windowState == open)`.

Comment: @Ben yes good point. That example works with the `&&` operator.  There are examples where it's not quite that simple, though.  See KennyTM's answer to see what I mean.

Comment: @Ben, @Neil: Ben is right; as I pointed out in my answer below, BUT is semantically equivalent to AND. KennyTM's answer deals only with the logic of the second version you supply: (!a ||(a && !b)).

Comment: @Neil: You've added an "English" version of what you're trying to achieve: 
"if the checkbox is checked but nothing is selected".
How is this different from:
"if the checkbox is checked AND nothing is selected" ??

Comment: @Irish Ahh okay, yes. So the point is that how would you understand what "but" meant. My examples were meant to be the same, but since "but" could be interpreted as "and" (and therefore "&&") it looks like they're different things.  Understood.

Comment: @Irish because if the checkbox is unchecked, the statement would not run, and that's not the desired behaviour.  Either it's unchecked, or it's checked and something is selected.

Comment: @Neil: If that's what you intend, then it bears little resemblance to the everyday semantics of BUT. It is also not the same as your sentence, "if the checkbox is checked but nothing is selected".

Comment: If you replace "but" with "and" it still makes sense, and would fit the language already in place.

Comment: An "and not" operator for booleans is probably not particularly useful, but IMHO one for numeric types would be very useful.  If var1 is bigger than var2, the statement "var1 &= ~var2;" may clear all the upper bits in var1 (rather than just those bits which are set in var2).  If there were a ~& operator (along with ~&=) that problem could be avoided.

Answer (score 9):

```
(a but b)  ==  (!a || (a && !b))
           ==  ((!a || a) && (!a || !b))
           ==  (!a || !b)
```

hence

```
if (!checkBox.Checked || comboBox.SelectedItem != null) { ... }
```

I find that this isn't much less readable than creating a new operator. Moreover, `and`, `or`, `not` have well-establish meanings in programming languages for Boolean variables, but `but` isn't, so you'll need a waste a line of documentation explaining `(a but b) == (!a || !b)`, instead of `a && !b` or `a && b` to everyone. It doesn't worth it.

Comment: and `(!a || !b) == !(a && b)`

Comment: Lol couldn't see the wood for the trees.  Thing is, that's kind've my point - I want to convey the *intention* better - and these kind've double-negative-and-or type expressions can often be the source of hard-to-spot bugs.

Comment: +1 I find it easier to understand using the existing operators rather than creating a new operator which I would have to learn.

Comment: I.e. "if the checkbox is not checked or the selected item is not null" doesn't scan well.  I'd like to write code that expresses the intention: "if the checkbox is checked but nothing is selected".

Comment: @Neil: Should that be just `checkbox.Checked && comboBox.SelectedItem != null` then? Why there is a `checkbox.Checked == false`?

Comment: @Kenny: close, but I think `checkbox.Checked && comboBox.SelectedItem == null`

Comment: @KennyTM because I don't care about nothing being selected if the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: My point is that there's an implicit "but" in the statement: "if the checkbox is unchecked or (it is **but**) nothing is selected...

Comment: @KennyTM, @Neil: I don't think this is the "correct" answer: it is fine from the second line onwards, but the initial premise (a but b)  ==  (!a || (a && !b)) is FALSE for the normal English defintion of "BUT". (Not the answerer's fault; the whole question has a false premise.)

Answer (score 4):

What stops you from writing a But Extension method?

```
public static bool But(this bool original, bool secondExpression)
{
  return original || (original && secondExpression));

}
```

This is better in my opinion as it promotes programming INTO a language opposed to just using one.

Comment: That reduces to `return original`.

Comment: ahahha! I just realized the short circuit would return true immediately if original was true.

Answer (score 2):

I think that "but" means the same as "and"! E.g.
"I like C# BUT I hate C++" means the same thing as "I like C# AND I hate C++". Both of them are conjunctions (joining statements).

In your example, surely you only want the body of the if statement to be executed in a situation where the combobox is checked but there is not selected item? This implies that for it to file, the combobox must be checked; i.e.:
checkBox.Checked && comboBox.SelectedItem == null

Therefore, I think your example of what 'but' should translate to is incorrect.

My C# is rusty, but if there is a way of defining something like macros in C#, you could define "but" as an alias for "&&", but I think it would yield very little benefit.

Comment: The || will short circuit if the first expression bombs.

Comment: No - I want the body of the statement to be executed if the checkbox is unchecked, or if it's checked, but nothing was selected.

Comment: Neil: If you want the statement to be executed if the checkbox is unchecked, that is not what everyday semantics of the word BUT would imply! So you need to think of a different word for this operator.

Answer (score 1):

If we start here, where does it end. However, if you like such things, maybe Boo is for you. This allows you to add your own syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, you could write:

```
if ($checkBox.Checked) doSomething() unless (!$comboBox.SelectedItem);
```

Personally, I'm very much in favour of more expressive languages, but that has to be balanced against the pain caused by [TMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).

Comment: Every popular language exhibits TMTOWTDI.  This is almost an aphorism: not all programmers think exactly alike, and if there's only one way to express something, then programmers have to learn to think that way before using the language, which prevents it from becoming popular.  Also, programming generally follows the rule: You can have it fast, simple, or correct, but you're lucky to get two and never all three.